# Replacing a string that contains vowels with '_'

Tags: java

I am trying to write a program that prints an inputted user string with the vowels replaced as _. I am having trouble at the if part where the program won't print due to a compile error.

```java
import java.util.Scanner;
public class mathpowers {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter string: ");
        String s = a.nextLine();
        int count = 0;
        for (char c : s.toCharArray())
        {
            if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
            {
                c = '_';
                System.out.println (c[i]);
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Your string has " + count + " upper case letters.");
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the compile error you're getting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code suffers from many problems and doesn't compile.

- Replace `c[i]` with `c`. `c` is a `char`, not a `String`. (*You don't even have an `i`...*)
- You are printing `count`, but you never increment it.
- Even if you'll count `count`, you're counting vowels and not upper cases as you printed.
- You are assigning `"_"` to `c` and printing it, your output will be always `_`.

Maybe you want to do something like this:

```
Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter string: ");
String s = a.nextLine();
String res = "";
for (char c : s.toCharArray())
{
    if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
        res = res + '_';
    }
    else
        res = res + c;
}
System.out.println(res); //Will contain the string with the vowels replaced with _
```

Or.. better code:

```
Scanner a = new Scanner (System.in);
System.out.print("Enter string: ");
String s = a.nextLine();
String[] vals = {"a", "u", "o", "e", "i"};
for(String val : vals)
    s = s.replaceAll(val, "_");
System.out.println(s);
```

Comment: This is probably an homework/assignment, don't think OP need's regex. but obviously a good solution. think it'd be good if you explain whats happening in your code

Comment: yeah I am new to arrays didn't realize the system.out.print(c) and not c[i]. That fixed the problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
System.out.println(c[i]);
```

should be

```
System.out.println(c);
```

Comment: +1, hehe, i was staring at the code for last 2 min's ..  :P good spot

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, need need the `import` keyword in front of `java.util.Scanner;` on your first line.
You also need to remove an extra `{` in the code below

```
if (c=='a' || c=='e' || c=='i' || c=='o' || c=='u') {
{ //<- This is not needed as you have another on on the end of the line above
c = '_';
System.out.println (c[i]);
}
}
```

Also `c` in the code above is a `char` not an array so you only need to call `System.out.println (c);` but you also just assign `'_'` to c before calling so you'll only ever print out `_`. Another problem is that you are only changing values in the array created by `s.toCharArray()` so you'll need to make this call before the for loop and then after the loop use it to create a new string to assign to `s`.

Finally, you never increase `count` so you last print out will always say 0 but I guess you'll solve that later.

If you are not already using an Integrated Development Environment (IDE) like [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/) or [NetBeans](http://netbeans.org/downloads/) I recommend you download one as it will highlight these bugs to you like a word processor highlights spelling and grammar mistakes.